# MAMP wont connect to mySQL

Tags: macos, installation, server, mamp

I have installed and configure MAMP on my MAC (Yosemite operating system. I used the how to video on Lynda.com:

http://www.lynda.com/WordPress-tutorials/Downloading-installing-WordPress/361682/370433-4.html

At the end of the video he clicks start servers and it bring him to a locally hosted MAMP webpage. The Apache server runs correctly. How do I get mySQL to run correctly? Mysqlb is not running.

Comment: Maybe tell us the errors you see? Maybe show us how your config files look?

Comment: There is no error the it simply does the loading symbol and never pops up the webpage. The Apache server does connect. How do I access my config files?